# ASP Send response right away then process more

Tags: multithreading, asp-classic, response

I am creating a web service. The client sends information in XML to a RETURN URL via POST. The client is supposed to only receive "Success" or "Fail" which is just a status indicator to confirm that the RETURN URL did received the POST message.

After that, the RETURN URL (host) will process the XML data that the client sent.

The problem I am having is that the processing may take minutes. I want to send the status message right away, then continue with processing the XML data.

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: check if `Response.Flush()` can be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this. The first one that comes to mind is to store the XML in a database record and return the "success" status to the client.

Set up a process to run every few seconds or minutes that checks for new records in the database and processes them until there are no more.

I implemented a group texting service in ASP this way once. Incoming SMS messages (like your incoming XML files) were stored in a database. A process ran every minute or two that looked for new messages and did whatever the message told them to do. If the message was a command to send a new message to the group, those outgoing messages were put into another database and another process ran periodically that sent those messages. It would send messages until it reached a limit prescribed by the carriers on how many messages per minute it could send, then it would terminate.

This was all done in classic ASP with a third-party scheduler running on the server. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You should poll the server every so often (you decide) until you get the "completed" response.

Comment: Can't do that. There's no point. The client does not care whether process is completed or not. It just needs the confirmation from host that it received the XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Set your web service to return as asynchronous.  If your doing it in .Net there is a parameter you put on the web service function

[MSDN Asynchronous web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480512.aspx)

If your creating it in Java here's some information how to do it from Oracle.  I'm not as familar with Java so I'm not sure exactly how it's done but here's a doc on it.

[Oracle Asynchronous web service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm)